# Read specific number of lines in python

Tags: python, data-mining, large-data

I have the BIG data text file for example:

```
#01textline1
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 5 6 7 3
3 5 6 7 6 4
4 6 7 8 9 9

1 2 3 6 4 7
3 5 7 7 8 4
4 6 6 7 8 5

3 4 5 6 7 8
4 6 7 8 8 9
..
..
```

Comment: The indentation looks incorrect

Comment: have you read this? https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html

Comment: In addition to the indentation issue, you are opening file2 with a "r" flag. The line == "#03textline3" isn't breaking because there is a newline (\n) character which is causing your conditional to fail. You could make it if "#03textline3" in line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need a loop to accomplish your purpose. Just use the `index` function on the list to get the index of the two lines and take all the lines between them.

Note that I changed your `file.readlines()` to strip trailing newlines.

(Using `file.read().splitlines()` can fail, if `read()` ends in the middle of a line of data.)

```
file1 = open("data.txt","r")
file2=open("newdata.txt","w")
lines = [ line.rstrip() for line in file1.readlines() ]

firstIndex = lines.index("#02textline2")
secondIndex = lines.index("#03textline3")

print firstIndex, secondIndex
file2.write("\n".join(lines[firstIndex  + 1 : secondIndex]))


file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Comment: There's really no need to load and process the whole file

Comment: @wnnmaw, That is a very fair point, but the OP's original solution already read the entire file into memory, so I tried to stay as close to it as possible while also making the logic as clean as possible.

Comment: @wnnmaw, The underlying assumption is that the file is sufficiently small that the cost of reading it into memory is not high enough for the OP to care.

Answer (score 1):

There is a line return character at the end of every line, so this:

```
if line == "#03textline3":
```

will never be true, as the line is actually `"#03textline3\n"`. Why didn't you use the same syntax as the one you used for `"#02textline2"` ? It would have worked:

```
if "#03textline3" in line: # Or ' line == "#03textline3\n" '
    break;
```

Besides, you have to correct your indentation for the `always_print = True` line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would suggest doing:

```
firstKey = "#02textline2"
secondKey = "#03textline3"

with open("data.txt","r") as fread:
    for line in fread:
        if line.rstrip() == firstKey:
            break

    with open("newdata.txt","w") as fwrite:
        for line in fread:
            if line.rstrip() == secondKey:
                break
            else:
                fwrite.write(line)
```

This approach takes advantage of the fact that Python treats files like iterators.  The first `for` loops iterates through the file iterator `f` until the first key is found.  The loop breaks, but the iterator stays as the current position.  When it gets picked back up, the second loops starts where the first let off.  We then directly write the lines you want to a new file, and discard the rest

**Advantages:**

- This does not load the entire file into memory, only the lines between `firstKey` and `secondKey` are stored, and only the lines before `secondKey` are ever read by the script
- No entries are looked over or processed more than once
- The context manager [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) is a safer way to consume files